# PHP MySQL - Generate generic query, issue with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, generics, foreach

I am trying to generate a generic query from RunFieldName table but I am getting an issue while I am trying to generate the generic query into my foreach loop. it takes only my last value.

Here my RunFiledName table Structure:

```
+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| FieldName             | ShortNameEcht | duplicate     |
+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
| 3SA46FEDa combined %  | 3SA46FED      | a combined %  |
| 3SA46FEDa combined of | 3SA46FED      | a combined of |
| 3SA46FEDa forward %   | 3SA46FED      | a forward %   |
| 3SA46FEDa forward of  | 3SA46FED      | a forward of  |
| 3SA46FEDa reverse %   | 3SA46FED      | a reverse %   |
| 3SA46FEDa reverse of  | 3SA46FED      | a reverse of  |
| 3SA46FEDb combined %  | 3SA46FED      | b combined %  |
| 3SA46FEDb combined of | 3SA46FED      | b combined of |
| 3SA46FEDb forward %   | 3SA46FED      | b forward %   |
| 3SA46FEDb forward of  | 3SA46FED      | b forward of  |
| 3SA46FEDb reverse %   | 3SA46FED      | b reverse %   |
| 3SA46FEDb reverse of  | 3SA46FED      | b reverse of  |
+-----------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

My desired ouput should look likes this:

```
INSERT INTO GenericTable SELECT '3SA46FED',`Reference`, `3SA46FEDa combined %`, `3SA46FEDa combined of`, `3SA46FEDa forward %`,`3SA46FEDa forward of`, `3SA46FEDa reverse %`, `3SA46FEDa reverse of`;
```

Here's what I tried to do with my php script:

```
<?php
$SqlRun = 'Select distinct ShortNameEcht, FieldName from RunFieldName';
$SqlEcht = 'Select distinct FieldName from RunFieldName';
$resultSQLRUN=mysqli_query($conn, $SqlRun);
$resultSQLEcht=mysqli_query($conn,$SqlEcht) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
while($rowEcht = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSQLRUN))
{
$columnsEcht[]=$rowEcht['ShortNameEcht'];
$columnsDup[]=$rowEcht['FieldName'];
}
foreach (array_combine($columnsEcht,$columnsDup ) as $val=>$val2){
$sql='insert into PIVOTtestGeneric SELECT "'.$val.'",`Reference`,
         `'.$val.''.$val2.'`,`'.$val.''.$val2.'`
         ,`'.$val.''.$val2.'`, `'.$val.''.$val2.'`, `'.$val.''.$val2.'`, `'.$val.''.$val2.'`,
         `'.$val.''.$val2.'`,`'.$val.''.$val2.'`
         ,`'.$val.''.$val2.'`, `'.$val.''.$val2.'`, `'.$val.''.$val2.'`, `'.$val.''.$val2.'`
         FROM runtable;';
echo $sql.'<br/>';

}
?>
```

I aslo tried to change my loop into foreach statement by doing:

```
    while($rowEchtDup = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSQLEcht))
    {
    $columnsDup[]=$rowEchtDup['FieldName'];
    }
    foreach($columnsEcht as $ind=>$val){
    foreach($columnsDup as $indd=>val2){
    $sql='insert into PIVOTtestGeneric SELECT "'.$val.'",`Reference`,
    '.$val2.' from runtable;';
echo $sql;
    }}
```

But it doesn't output what I want.

Comment: Horrible approach. You are generating $sql every time in foreach. You should seriously learn some basics.

Comment: @Indrajit, sorry dude, I didn't find any other way to do. I am ready to learn a new approach!

Comment: what is the result of this: array_combine($columnsEcht,$columnsDup ). Please check yourself and post if you feel is correct.

Comment: array_combine($columnsEcht,$columnsDup ) displayed only the lastest values of RunFieldName table.